# Is there a Powershell command to return a firewall's running firmware version?

Tags: powershell

I'm making a Powershell script that would return me the firewall's running firmware version. I ran the following command:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile
```

However, it does not return me the firmware version.

I'm running the script from a PC that can remotely invoke the commands on another PC which has the access rights to the firewall. How can I get its firmware version with Powershell?

Comment: A hardware firewall has a firmware, the cmdlet `Get-NetFirewallProfile` cite from Get-Help `Displays settings that apply to the per-profile configurations of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.`

Comment: You need to look to the firewall vendor and ask them how to programmatically read firmware info. If that vendor has a framework or command or exe or the like to leverage, then that is what you have to go with. For example on Cisco, you'd just do --- show version - many first tier firewall vendors have a PowerShell module or you can just use SSH to them and run their commands.